# extjs treepanel weird behavior after click on + to expand

Tags: extjs

I'm building a treepanel and when I click the `+` icon to expand nodes or `-` to collapse nodes the tree does a very weird behavior, I mean this:

[image: weird_tree_behavior]

the `select` and `itemdblclick` events are working as espected.

Also, I've attached these events:

```
beforeitemexpand: function(item, eOpts) {
                   ...
                },
                beforeitemcollapse: function(item, eOpts) {
                    ...
                },
                beforeexpand: function(panel, animate, eOPts) {
                    ...
                },
                beforecollapse: function(panel, animate, eOPts) {
                    ...
                }
```

none of them works.

Here is my treepanel view code:

```
Ext.define('mycomponent.mytreepanelview', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    itemId: 'mytreewindow',
    id: 'mytreewindow',
    xtype: 'mytreewindow',
    modal: true,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    height: 450,
    width: 375,
    closeAction: 'destroy',
    resizable: false,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'label',
            text: '?????'
        },
        {
            id: 'mytree',
            xtype: 'treepanel',
            border: true,
            width: 345,
            height: 325,
            title: '',
            rootVisible: false,
            header: false,
            displayField: 'text',
            store: Ext.create('mycomponent.store', {}),
            viewConfig: {
                preserveScrollOnRefresh: true,
                toggleOnDblClick: false
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'label',
            text: '??????'
        }
    ],
    buttons: [
        {
            itemId: 'okButton',
            id: 'okButton',
            text: 'Ok'
        },
        {
            itemId: 'cancelButton',
            id: 'cancelButton',
            text: 'Cancel'
        }
    ],

    initComponent: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        dtzerp.getController('mycomponent.mycontroller');
    },

    constructor: function (config) {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.initConfig(config);
        return this;
   }
});
```

Also, here is my store:

```
Ext.define('mycomponent.mystore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    alias: 'store.mystore',
    storeId: 'mystore',
    model: Ext.create('mycomponent.mymodel'),
    restful: true,
    autoLoad: false,
    root: {
        text: 'Loading...',
        id: 'NULL',
        expanded: true,
        loaded: true
    },
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        headers: {
           'Accept': '*/*',
           'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Authorization': localStorage.token
        },
        extraParams: {
           sort: 'name',
           'filter[active]': true,
           'filter[idparent][null]': 0
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data',
            successProperty: 'success'
        },
        api: {
           read: 'http://myurl',
           create: 'http://myurl',
           update: 'http://myurl',
           destroy: 'http://myurl'
        }
    },
    constructor: function (config) {
        config = Ext.apply({
            rootProperty: Ext.clone(this.rootData)
        }, config);

        this.callParent([config]);
    }
});
```

Moreover, the data that came from the rest api is always an array with the data in the selected node, that is to say, only the children of the selected node, if it has any.

On the first call, the rest api will return something like this:

```
[
  {id: '1', name: 'One', text: 'Item one', leaf: false, idparent: null}, 
  {id: '2', name: 'Two', text: 'Item two', leaf: false, idparent: null}, 
  {id: '3', name: 'Three', text: 'Item three', leaf: true, idparent: null}
]
```

then, if I select first item the rest api will return something like this:

```
[
   {id: '4', name: 'Child 1-1', text: 'Child 1 of 1', leaf: false: idparent: '1'},
   {id: '5', name: 'Child 2-1', text: 'Child 2 of 1', leaf: true: idparent: '1'}
]
```

and so on...

**UPDATE**
I'm commanding the store (Ext.data.TreeStore) to load on the `show` event of the window which contains the treepanel. This is in the controller:

```
  init: function () {
            this.control({
               '#mytreewindow': {
                   show: function (item, eOPts) {
                     var store = Ext.getStore('mytreestore');
                     var children = [];
                     var that = this;

                     store.load({
                         callback: function (records) {
                             debugger;
                             console.log(records);

                             var children = [
                               {text: 'testing',
                                leaf: false,
                                idparent: null,
                                idelement: 1,
                                children: [{idparent: 1,
                                            text: 'testing child',
                                            idelement: 2,
                                            leaf: true,
                                            children: []
                               }
                             ];
                             store.loadData(children, false);
                         }
```

the store enters into the callback, but when `debugger` stops the execution the tree is filled with the data from the rest-api, right before the callback is executed. So, after `store.loadData(...` the tree updates with the new info, but, when click the node `+` in the node `testing` it goes back to the same as in the image.

Are there any property I'm missing, or any configuration that I need to add in order to avoid this weird behavior?

Comment: Can you attach the example on fiddle? What data is in the store?

Comment: @norbeq the store data is from a rest api, and the tree is beign loaded on demand

Comment: @norbeq I've updated the question with the store

Comment: I mean store data instead of store definition. You need to attach example (even better on the fiddle) to explain where is the problem and can be recreated.

Comment: I just updated my answer. You need to do request and in callback just add childs and expand the node again. Look on refreshed example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override `onBeforeExpand` method in your `Ext.tree.View` in `Ext.tree.Panel`.

You can do it like :

```
viewConfig: {
    onBeforeExpand: function (n) {
        if (n.childNodes.length === 0) {
            //HERE YOU MUST DO REQUEST AND IN CALLBACK:
            n.appendChild(twoItemNodes);
            n.expand();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Look example on fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2sbc

Comment: I'm not sure if understand your response. I have a callback after store load is complete and there is where I add items into the selected node. How can I put this snippet of code inside that callback? I mean, in your example you are telling to put the load method and callback in the view, not in the controller... is there a way to call `viewConfig: { onBeforeExpand: ...` from the controller?

Comment: Why do you want to `call` viewConfig... from the controller? You can set viewConfig in controller when you create new instance of view. Can you attach the controller code and the code of creating view?

Comment: I'm not calling viewconfig from the controller, but from the view. Why is the treepanel doing such weird thing when the data is coming from a restapi?

Comment: Because when you click - there isn't data yet. I don't know your application architecture. Where do you create the window `mytreewindow`? Can you attach this code?

Comment: I call that window from a controller: on the event click of a button I set this: `var treewin = Ext.create('mycomponent.mytreewindow');` and then `treewin.show();`

Comment: I gave you an example of dynamically loading data. No one will do this without any functional example. Anyway, using the same store to `load` data and then use `loadData` on the same store in my opinion is bad pattern. Next, if node in tree store isn't leaf then children shouldn't be empty (here is problem). And the finally, explore the ViewController to get easy references between views and stores.

Comment: I don't know how to upload a functional example via fiddle. Moreover, I'm using `loadData` because I need to reformat the code that comes from the restapi so the extjs can read it.

Comment: So you should use Ext.Ajax and create store locally instead.